# No webcam picture since using it on Gmail

Tags: windows-xp, logitech-webcam

I have a [Logitech Sphere AF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/QuickCam) webcam, using Windows XP SP3.

I've been using Logitech's own software to record video diaries. Today I used Gmail for the first time to video chat with a friend - since then I can no longer receive a picture when trying to use Logitech's software. The camera responds to tilt/pan controls and the operating light is on, but just only a blue screen shows. I've just added a USB extension cable (it has a booster built in). I logged back into Gmail and an image showed up fine there, but there is no picture elsewhere.

What could be causing the problem, and how I could fix it?

Comment: Does the logitech software have an option that lets you pick the input source? (For example, if you have multiple cameras attached to one computer.)

Answer (score 1):

If it were other things than Gmail... I mean, with other kind of software, I would say your driver might have been overwritten, or its settings, some conflict, and so I'd try and install the webcam's drivers and software again, provided there's no harm/loss on doing that. If there isn't, indeed, I'd first uninstall stuff that might have got installed related to video, also then the webcam drivers and software, and reinstall them again. Then see if it all gets back to normal.

Answer (score 0):

Try unplugging it and then plugging it back in again, preferably into a different usb port. (with your web browser closed)

See if it then works fine in logitech's software before moving forward to see why gmail 'might' be breaking it. (Can't be sure yet if gmail is at fault)